# Building query string GET vars dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm head below water on this, using Laravel I have a search page of which ajax calls a url and updates the html for filter by the way of html links which contain get vars `($(this).attr('href');` which contains `?var=test` sent via ajax) to return filtered results. As ajax this doesn't update the url I'm using `history.replaceState` to update that.

Now here's my issue, the links which be shown as buttons (using BS) - so my link href will include the `?thisbuttonvar=whatever` BUT if that get var already exists then the link href should not include `?thisbuttonvar=whatever` it should remove it

I have created a function to try to handle this as follows (sorry I can't get it to paste properly):

```
function href_append_query($param) {

    parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $query_array);
    if (array_key_exists(current(array_keys($param)), $query_array))
    {
        $key = current(array_keys($param));

        if ($param[$key] == $query_array[$key])
        {
            unset($query_array[$key]);
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        $query_array = $query_array + $param;
    }

    $query = http_build_query($query_array);

    return '?' . $query; }
```

The issue with this is when I do a

```
    @foreach ($category->subCategories()->get() as $sub_category)
                <li><a class="search-filter" href=<?=href_append_query(['sub_category' => $sub_category->sub_category_url])?>>{!! $sub_category->sub_category !!}</a></li>
```

It works for the first link, but all the rest of my href's come back the same (as the first one that enters the function)

Can anyone assist in getting this function to work so the foreach link has the appropriate href OR an entirely different "easier" way all together :)

My jQuery if it helps paint a better picture

```
$(document).on("click", '.search-filter', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 

    $('#spinner-modal').modal('show');
    $('#spinner-modal p').html('<b>Searching,</b> please wait...<br />');

    query = $(this).attr('href');
    history.replaceState(null, null, query);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url : query,            
        success : function(data, status){ 

            $('#job-results').html(data);
            $('#spinner-modal').modal('hide');   

        },
        error : function(status){
            console.log(status);
        },
    });  

});
```

Comment: So your purpose is if you have already a query parameter it will not include again that?

Comment: Yeah, it will in fact remove it if the link is selected again. I think I've just figured it out, the issue is when there is only one parameter being the one removed $query_array = $query_array (this will be empty!) + $param; reversing to $param + $query_array seems to have solved my issue I think.